# Using jquery ajax jsonp to read .txt file that contains json syntax

Tags: jquery, json, jsonp

A .txt file on a remote server contains json syntax that I need to retrieve. I am using jsonp because it is on another domain.

I have tried like this :

```
$.getJSON('http://www.server1.com/json.txt'+'?callback=?', function(data){
    console.log(data);    
});
```

The .txt file is [here](http://goo.gl/2XuHm4) 
But I get an error when the first name - value pair of the json is "parsed" :

> Unexpected token :

I have tried changing the txt.json and added a `var mydata={ jsonSyntax }` and this way I don't get the error but no data is logged to the console. 
So how can I request and parse json.txt with jsonp?

Comment: For JSONP to work shouldn't you be using $.getScript instead of $.getJSON?

Comment: Most likely your json isn't jsonp, which is why requesting it as JSONP fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jsonp works by wrapping the data on the server in a callback function. Most servers will allow you to specify the callback. Since you have a static text file, you need to hard-code a function name into the text file, then specify that name as a parameter in your ajax call.

Change the `json.txt` file to this:

`callback({ jsondata });`

And your ajax call to this:

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    jsonpCallback: 'callback'
}).done(function(data) { 
    console.log(data); 
});
```